# here map iOS distanceToDestination

Tags: ios, gps

I wonder if someone can help me get total route distance in Heremap iOS sdk.  According to the document, the following should do it, but I only ever get back values that borders on infinity, and that' just evil.  Can someone please provide a working example?  I am running this in the simulator but that shouldn't really matter.

```
unsigned long long distance_ul = [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].distanceToDestination;

NMAUint64 distance_i64 = [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].distanceToDestination;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second usage `NMAUint64 distance = [NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager].distanceToDestination;` is ok. Then you should calculate your distance by yourself. Below is an example for the metric system

```
- (NSString *)distanceToMetricStringFromLongValue:(NMAUint64)value {
    NSString *distanceText = @"";
    if (value < 250) {
        NMAUint64 distance = (NMAUint64)round(value / 5.0) * 5;
        if (showZeroDistance || distance > 0) {
            distanceText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld m", distance];
        }
    } else if (value < 500) {
        NMAUint64 distance = (NMAUint64)round(value / 10.0) * 10;
        if (showZeroDistance || distance > 0) {
            distanceText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld m", distance];
        }
    } else if (value < 1000) {
        NMAUint64 distance = (NMAUint64)round(value / 50.0) * 50;
        distanceText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld m", distance];
    } else {
        double distance = value / 1000.0;
        if (distance >= 10.0) {
            distanceText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f km", round(distance)];
        } else {
            distanceText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f km", distance];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create route on map with below method

```
- (nullable NSProgress *)calculateRouteWithStops:(nonnull NSArray *)stops
                                     routingMode:(nonnull NMARoutingMode *)mode
                                 completionBlock:(nullable NMACalculateResultBlock)completion
```

Find route length from `NMARoute` object

```
NMARoute* route = routeResult.routes[m];
NSLog(@"Route Length is :----- %lu",(unsigned long)route.length);
```

[Official document link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-starter/topics_api_nlp/interfacenmaroute.html)